# log4j in grails : how to log into file?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, log4j, dsl

I have this log4j configuration in my grails config.groovy

```
log4j = {
    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers
                   'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages' //  GSP
    warn 'org.mortbay.log' 


    appenders {
        rollingFile  name:'infoLog', file:'info.log', threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.INFO, maxFileSize:1024
        rollingFile  name:'warnLog', file:'warn.log', threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.WARN, maxFileSize:1024
        rollingFile  name:'errorLog', file:'error.log', threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.ERROR, maxFileSize:1024
        rollingFile  name:'custom', file:'custom.log', maxFileSize:1024
    }

    root {
        info 'infoLog','warnLog','errorLog','custom', stdout
        error()
        additivity = true
    }
}
```

the infoLog,warnLog and errorLog was from the previous question ... they were working well.

now I add new RollingFile wit name "custom" ...

I tried to log from my controller and service using log.info("something .... ${obj}");
but it seems that message was not inserted into custom.log, do I need to add something to the configuration ?

thank you !!

Comment: Aren't you missing the threshold value?

Comment: As I'm looking over your code, I think that -- stout -- should be quoted ("stout")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just got answer from the grails' mailing list:

i just need to add

debug "grails.app"

bellow warn "org.mortbay.log"

case closed ! :)

Comment: even if i use a custom appender it always ends up in the root appender as well. And if i remove my appender from the root then it does not work at all. Any way to prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 0):

I have exact the same jetty/tomcat env's. Spent hours to figure it out. The trick is to define the file location (a relative path in my case) as a global variable inside Config.groovy, customized it in the environment blocks, and use the variable location inside log4j closure. Sample code is at: http://denistek.blogspot.com/2010/02/grails-environment-specific-logging-to.html

Answer (score 0):

please see [Log4j: How to write to a specific appender?](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Log4j-How-to-write-to-a-specific-appender-td1383692.html)

> After all the solution is to put the additivity setting to the package configuration:
>
> `info specialLog:'activityLog', additivity:false`